# Как с помощью testinfra molecule проверить файл конфигурации?

Tags: ansible

В molecule простая задача по установке haproxy, копированию его файла конфигурации и запуску.
Testinfra проверяет выполнение.
Как проверить, что файл конфигурации соответствует тому, что файл именно тот?

Comment: Эээ... ну у ансибла модуль `copy` этим занимается и он как бы сампроверяет скопировался файл нормально или нет. Тебе что конкретно надо?